# regex check if url has trailing slash and params

Tags: regex, wordpress, redirect

i need a check on regex, in particular:

```
/it/categoria/diritti-e-ugualianza
/it/categoria/diritti-e-ugualianza/
/it/categoria/diritti-e-ugualianza?i=1
/it/categoria/diritti-e-ugualianza/?i=1
```

must be checked in a unique rule

i try with this

```
/it/categoria/diritti-e-ugualianza(?:/(.*))?$
```

but it works only with
    /it/categoria/diritti-e-ugualianza
    /it/categoria/diritti-e-ugualianza/

exists a way to ignore also params?
thank you

Comment: Try [`/it/categoria/diritti-e-ugualianza(?:[?/](.*))?$`](https://regex101.com/r/gmyEHm/1), replace `/` with `[/?]`.

Comment: What's your context? There is often a built-in function to get that information.

Comment: i use Redirections a wordpress plugin, that manage 301 redirect, when a url are called, the plugin match with all rules, and if there is a rule correct redirect to another page (is another param) 

so i need a matching regex

Comment: @AndreaG.Pigliafreddo Please add relevant tag to the question to get relevant help.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your solution it works, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may replace `/` with a character class `[/?]` that matches either `?` or `/`:

```
/it/categoria/diritti-e-ugualianza(?:[?/](.*))?$
                                     ^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gmyEHm/1).

**Details**

- `/it/categoria/diritti-e-ugualianza` - a literal substring
- `(?:[?/](.*))?` - an optional group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `[?/]` - a `?` or `/`
  - `(.*)` - Capturing group 1: any 0+ chars to the end of the line
- `$` - end of string.